# Formik: Llamar petición asíncrona al establecer un select que tiene dependientes

Tags: reactjs, async-await, async

Tengo 3 selects que funcionan de manera asíncrona: `contry`, `state` y `city`.

Los `onChange` de `contry` y `state` hacen peticiones al API de lugares y cambian las opciones de `state` y `city` respectivamente.

El `initialValues` contiene id de los lugares pero solo cambia `contry` y no los demás porque no se manda a llamar el `onChange` de `contry` al iniciar.

```
useEffect(() => {
 GetAlgo().then(res => {
  setAlgo(res.data)
 })
}, []);
...
<Field
 name="contry"
 as="select"
value={props.values.contry}
 >
  <option>Seleccione</option>
   {contries.map((contry: any) => (
    <option key={contry.contryID} value={contry.contryID}>
     {contry.contryName}
    <option>
    ))}
    </Field>
```

Comment: No termino de entender cuál sería el problema. Tal vez le falta más información a tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya resolví el problema, me referia a que como city depende de state y state depende de country, al establecerse los valores iniciales solo country carga sus countries y se pone valor inicial, los demás ni los cargan https://formik.org/docs/examples/dependent-fields-async-api-request